# How do I install ubuntu to my C drive?

Tags: dual-boot

When installing ubuntu, I confirmed the option to *install alongside my existing windows 10*.
Then when I proceeded to the next page, the only option of hard drives that could be selected was my **external hard drive**.  I want it on my C disk, so that I can select, at start up, which OS to use.
Why can't I get the Disc C showing as an install option?

Comment: to select either OS's it doesn't **need** to be on C drive (or windows drive), my suggestion would be to make some unallocated space in your internal drive and ubuntu should pick up that unallocated space.

Comment: The button that shows the name of your external hard drive on that page is actually a drop-down control. Click it and scroll to your internal disk. There is no "Disc C" by the way. What Windows calls "C:" is one partition on your internal disk, of which you can have several.

Comment: Thank you Sumeet, and Jos. I did create a vacant partition on my C disk before installing, but for some as yet undetermined reason, the install Menu did not scroll to my other drives. Only one option available, The Ext H/D. And the option to boot from start up, still only gives the 2 versions of Windows 10 i am running. No sign of Ubuntu,which installed on the Ext H/D

Answer (score 0):

A good nights sleep has cleared my brain.
The answer to my problem is this, ( a bit of general knowledge for all of us ) My C drive only allows 2 O/S partitions to be created. I already have 2 versions of Windows using those. 
Thats the reason the Ubuntu install, installed to my Ext H/D.
And the reason Ubuntu will not boot from that Drive is, my BIOS hardware only allows for 2 boot options, and they are taken up by my C drive and CD-ROM.
So for booting Ubuntu, i have to do it manually in the Boot menu at start up.
Thank you for responding to my question.